# How to create bootstrap list view in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have used the below code to show the items with image , it's working fine but not able to make it mobile compatible , i want to show a single column when it is viewed on mobile .in desktop it properly shows 4 columns

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Diary.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Itemview_test.aspx.vb"
 Inherits="itemview_test" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .container
        {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .row
        {
            height: 100%;
            display: table-row;
        }
        .col-sm-3
        {
            display: table-cell;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:ListView ID="lvCustomers" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1"
            GroupItemCount="4" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1" OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvCustomers" PageSize="50">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                    ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                                <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false"
                                    ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                            </Fields>
                        </asp:DataPager>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <asp:Image ID="picAlbum" runat="server" AlternateText='<% #Eval("acc_name") %>' ImageUrl='<%# "ShowImage1param.ashx?id=" + Eval("ac_id") %>' />
                            <br />
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" align="right" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("ac_id")%>'
                                Target="_blank" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%#Eval("ac_id")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
                            <br />
                            <%# Eval("acc_name")%>
                            <br />
                            <%# Eval("acc_group")%>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("comp_name")%>'></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" align="right" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("comp_website")%>'
                                Target="_blank" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%#Eval("comp_website")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Total" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("comp_address")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<div class="col-sm-3">` To `<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">` in the `<GroupTemplate>` and remove the `<div class="col-sm-3">` from the `<ItemTemplate>`.

I would also move the `<div class="container">` out of the `<GroupTemplate>` and put it in the `<LayoutTemplate>` wrapping all the content.

The result:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="lvCustomers" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1"
        GroupItemCount="4" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1" OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="container">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvCustomers" PageSize="50">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false"
                                ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <GroupTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
        </GroupTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <asp:Image ID="picAlbum" runat="server" AlternateText='<% #Eval("acc_name") %>' ImageUrl='<%# "ShowImage1param.ashx?id=" + Eval("ac_id") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" align="right" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("ac_id")%>'
                        Target="_blank" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%#Eval("ac_id")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    <br />
                    <%# Eval("acc_name")%>
                    <br />
                    <%# Eval("acc_group")%>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("comp_name")%>'></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" align="right" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("comp_website")%>'
                        Target="_blank" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%#Eval("comp_website")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Total" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("comp_address")%>'></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, have tried the same , but now it is showing a single column for desktop also.I want 4 column view on desktop and when the same page is viewed on mobile , it should be bootstrab single column display.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <ListView ID="RadListBoxes" runat="server" DataSourceID="BoxesInfoSource" DataKeyNames="Status">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="container-fluid" runat="server">
                <div class="row" runat="server">
                    <div id="itemPlaceholder" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" runat="server">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' runat="server" ID="StatusLabel" /><br />

                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Counts") %>' runat="server" ID="CountsLabel" /><br />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: pure bootstrap, binds to an SQLDATASOURCE Normally, no code behind and  (No Fuss!)